# Remove directory but not content using php

Tags: php

How to remove a directory maintaining the content on php?

For example:

I have this directory with files:

```
+ /home/user/files/arq1.mp3
+ /home/user/files/arq2.mp3
+ /home/user/files/arq3.mp3
```

And the PHP file is on:

```
+ /home/user/files.php
```

How to remove files directory but keep mp3 files on `/home/user/ directory`??

Comment: Move everything outside, then delete the folder.

Comment: But if I have more subdirectories? I need that this move all files on directory and subdirectories for the main.

Comment: What's the point of removing a directory if you want to keep the files inside it? Are you trying to rename the directory?

Comment: In this case, you need to iterate through all subdirectories

Comment: @Pier-LucGendreau I'm extracting a .rar or .zip file, then, I need all .mp3 files on it, but I can't have directories, just the files.

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis It's exactly what I don't know how to do.

Comment: On linux i would use: find . -type f | awk '{print "cp " $1 " ."}' | sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Approach:

```
foreach (glob("/home/user/files/*") as $file) {
    copy($file,"/home/user/".basename($file));
}
rmdir("/home/user/files/");
```

Terminal Approach:

```
mv /home/user/files/* /home/user/*
rmdir /home/user/files/
```

Comment: Almost perfect, I'll try to adapt this to my need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*nix approach :)

```
find . -type f | awk '{print "cp " $1 " ."}' | sh
```

If you are unsure about what it does try the bottom one first, that will only print the generated actions. Piping them to 'sh' executes them.

```
find . -type f | awk '{print "cp " $1 " ."}'
```

Ok :) PHP approach:

```
function flatten_structure( $path = './tree', $target_path = './flat' ) {
  $handle = opendir( $path );
  while( false !== ( $item = readdir( $handle ) ) ) {
    if ( is_file( $path . '/' . $item ) ) copy( $path . '/' . $item, $target_path );
    if ( is_dir( $path . '/' . $item ) ) flatten_structure( $path . '/' . $item, $target_path );
  }
}
```

Comment: +1, I'm not fluent with nix, but his server might be running this :)

Comment: I know how to do this on linux, but I'm trying to keep my code far from direct ssh commands.